# Difficulties while viewing the TD & TR

Tags: html, html-table

I am having difficulties while getting the values into a table format:

The previous format was:

```
<table border="1" width="84%" align="center" bgcolor=#66CCFF bordercolor=#000000 height="137">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" height="33">
        <p align="center">
        <span style="font-size: 8pt; font-weight:700">Name</span></td>
        <td height="33">
        <span style="font-size: 8pt; font-weight:700">Add Name</span></td>
```

Now the new format is that I am getting the data :

```
<ul class="paging"> 
<%  
    while(rs.next()){     
%> 
        <li><%=rs.getString("Name")%></li> 
<%     
    }     
    rs.close();     
%>     

</ul> 

<ul class="paging"> 
<%  
    while(rs.next()){     
%> 
        <li><%=rs.getString("add")%></li> 
<%     
    }     
    rs.close();     
%>     
</ul>
```

So, can you please help to adjust the table format and make it as the first example. I tried to put the whole thing in `<td>`, but the whole data became in one column along the page. The problem is that I would like to include the `<ul> <li>` in the table `<TD>` column.
So, the first column is having the name with the `<ul>` and next to it is the Add with the `<ul>` and selection.

Answer (score 0):

Wel rather than using `<ul>` & `<li>` tags in the result sets it will be preferable to used the `<tr>` & `<td>`'s.

Also, you can repeate the `<tr>` for the result sets & in that only mention `<td>` and your data to put in. No need to explicitly to give the class to each `<td>`,

So your code can be modified as follows:

`<%

    while(rs.next()){

%>   <tr class="pagings">

      <td colspan="2" >
      <%=rs.getString("Name")%> 
      </td> 
      <td> 
      <%=rs.getString("add")%>
      </td> 
     </tr>
<%

    }

    rs.close();

%>`

Try to implement the following changes so that you can get your solution. Let us know for any further help?